# how could I define a global module by typescript and not add to compiled file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-frontend

If a have a global module in a.ts:

```
export = class A(){

}
```

I want to import this module into a lot of .ts file, but when I do this, the module A will be compile to every file that I import module A.

So how can I define a global module, when I import it, this module will not be add to the compiled file.

my tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outFile": "index.js",
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
           "jQuery": ["types/jquery.d.ts"],
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
       "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: added, is any worry?

Comment: You have outFile configuration. So you have a single generated file. So how come module A is generated more than one time? In index.js or in other files?